# ODE: Euler iterative method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, numerical-methods

I´m doing some examples on the euler method to solve differential equations, and I came across this one:

> $\begin{cases} y'(t) = e^{-ty(t)} \\ y(0) = 1  \end{cases}$ 
>   for $t \in [0,1]$

I want't to show that $\mid y'(t) \mid < 1$ and $\mid y(t) \mid < 2$.

For the second one I can use the mean value theorem, and get an expression:

> $y(t) = t y'(t) + 1 = t e^{-ty(t)} + 1$

And using the bound for $y'(t)$ I get the bound that I need for $y(t)$. But I don't know how to show the bound for $y'(t)$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential equation tells you that $|y'| <1$ if $y>0$ for all x in the interval.  Can you show this?

Comment: From $y(t) = t y'(t) + 1 = t e^{-ty(t)} + 1$ and the fact that the exponential is a positive function I can show that $y(t) > 0$ in the interval [0,1], and now I can say that the product $t y(t)$ is positive in my interval, y'(t) is a decreasing function on t and has a maximum on t=0, wich gives the bound $\mid y'(t) \mid < 1$?

Comment: @Jasimud, exactly.